# Selenium not working in Python , Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, ubuntu

I installed selenium using pip. and placed geckodriver in /usr/bin .
I keep ubuntu updated. Firefox updated.

When I run below program :

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://google.com')
```

On running I got :

THE end.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "seleniumIntro.py", line 3, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 32, in <module>
    from .extension_connection import ExtensionConnection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 24, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import RemoteConnection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 35, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/utils.py", line 22, in <module>
    import zipfile
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 501, in <module>
    class ZipExtFile(io.BufferedIOBase):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BufferedIOBase'
```

---

(program exited with code: 1)
Press return to continue

Why is it happening ?
Thank you.

Comment: do you by chance have a module named `io` on your path?

Comment: how do I check it?

Comment: try `import io; io.__file__` from `Python` shell to check which `io` module actually used in your code

Comment: >>> io.__file__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'io' is not defined

Comment: You should import it first

Comment: Sorry: This one

Comment: '/usr/lib/python2.7/io.pyc'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working with python3 , installed using pip3 and just ran the same program.
Thank you for helping me.